# making an input box to accept alphanumeric characters

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following input box:

```
           <input id="address1"  class="work" />Address1
           <input id="address2"  class="work" />Address2
<input style="float: right; margin-bottom:20px" type="submit" id="myBtn" value="Submit" class="btn btn-primary"  />
```

I dont want user to type only digits in the input box. I want them to type both digits and alphabets. If the user only type digits then an error is raised when the user clicks on the submit button.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To make some validation before submitting the form when clicking `input[type="submit"]`, you can do this with `.click()` and return it with `false`. This way will block submit event and possibly display any errors if exists. Then, put this regex

```
/\d.*[a-zA-Z]|[a-zA-Z].*\d/
```

as validation to get both numbers and alphabets in a string.

---

**Edit: Regex explanation**

That regex can be divided into 3 parts.

1. `\d.*[a-zA-Z]`: start with a digit (`\d`) and is followed by any number of characters (`.*`) before alphabets (`[a-zA-Z]`). (For example: `0a`, `1bb`, `00a` etc.)
2. `|`: `OR` expression.
3. `[a-zA-Z].*\d`: start with an alphabet (`[a-zA-Z]`) and is followed by any number of characters (`.*`) before any digits (`\d`). (For example: `a0`, `bb1`, `a00` etc.).

So, this regex (`/\d.*[a-zA-Z]|[a-zA-Z].*\d/`) matches any string that contains at least one digit and at least one alphabetical letter in any order.

---

```js
$('#myBtn').click((e)=>{
  let a1 = $('#address1');
  let a2 = $('#address2');
  let regex = /\d.*[a-zA-Z]|[a-zA-Z].*\d/;
  let errors = [];
  for(let a of [a1,a2]) {
    if(!regex.test(a.val())) {
      errors.push(a.attr('id') + ' does not contain both numbers and alphabets!');
    }
  }
  if(errors.length) {
    $('#errors').html(errors.join('<br />'));
    return false;
  }
});
```

```css
#errors {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
  <input id="address1"  class="work" />Address1
  <input id="address2"  class="work" />Address2
  <input style="float: right; margin-bottom:20px" type="submit" id="myBtn" value="Submit" class="btn btn-primary"  />
  <span id="errors" style="float: left; margin-bottom:20px"></span>
</form>
```

Comment: And can you explain your regexp? Especially this moment `[a-zA-Z]|[a-zA-Z]` .

Comment: I see that you left me a comment and then deleted it. And I see your explanation in the edited reply. Thanks! I apologize right away, I don't want to offend you, but your solution is incorrect, as is the explanation of the regexp. For example, `Street of roses` in your answer will return `false`. In short about your pattern: `\d` - this is redundant, and `[a-zA-Z]|[a-zA-Z]` does not make sense at all, because it is also the same as `[a-zA-Z]`. Best regards! ✌️

Comment: Street of roses - this is just an example, real streets like *Trans-manhattan Expy* will not pass either.

Comment: @imhvost Yes, it will return false because no number in that string. *I want them to type both digits and alphabets* - It means, the asker want at least one number and one alphabet. What did I miss?

Comment: For some reason, I took the question to mean that only letters can be entered. And in one of the comments, @Anjali wrote about it: _Accept alphabets, accept digits with alphabets, but do not accept only digits_.

Answer (score 0):

You can use pattern:

```
<input id="address1" pattern="[A-Za-z0-9]*[A-Za-z]+[A-Za-z0-9]*" class="work" />Address1
<input id="address2" pattern="[A-Za-z0-9]*[A-Za-z]+[A-Za-z0-9]*" class="work" />Address2
```

Comment: With the above pattern, the input box is accepting only digits. I want to restrict the user not to type only digits. user can type a combination of digits and alphabets test1 or 1test

Comment: You tested it? It accepts both digits and alphabets

Comment: Yes, it accepts both digits and alphabets, but if I only type digits and not alphabets then it doesn't complain

Comment: You mean it has to contain at least 1 digit and 1 alphabet?

Comment: It can have all alphabets, but not all digits. It can have combination of both digits and alphabets

Comment: It is still letting me type only digits.

Comment: I tried submit, it doesn't accept only digits. Maybe I don't understand what you need.

Comment: your answer does not have  submit button so I thought, it will pop up an error when I tab out. I will try with submit button.

Comment: I put this code underneath the input boxes: <input type="Submit" value="Submit"> and then type digits in the input box and clicked on submit button and it accepted the digits

Comment: It doesn't work correctly. For example `666 Terrible-Street` in your pattern will return `false`.

Answer (score 0):

`^.*[a-zA-Z].*$` - this pattern seems to work for you:

```html
<form>
  <label>
    <input pattern="^.*[a-zA-Z].*$" required>
    Address1
  </label>
  <label>
    <input pattern="^.*[a-zA-Z].*$" required>
    Address2
  </label>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

Answer (score -1):

**Please try this. This only accept alphanumeric characters in the input box**

```html
<input id="address1"  class="work"  onkeyup="this.value=this.value.replace(/[^A-z0-9]/g,'');"/>Address1
<input id="address2"  class="work"  onkeyup="this.value=this.value.replace(/[^A-z0-9]/g,'');"/>Address2
```

Comment: It doesn't let me type digits. If my address is 123 Test drive then it wont work or test 123 will not work either

Comment: @Anjali You want digits and alphabets right?  Like, "123 Test drive".                                    Please Use this  onkeyup="this.value=this.value.replace(/[^A-z0-9]/g,'')

Comment: Can you please edit your answer. I can easily try it then.

Comment: I tried only digits in the input box and it worked.

Comment: You can try typing only digits in the input box and tab out of it and the digits will be accepted. Let me know if I am missing something

Comment: @Anjali its working or not?

Comment: @ Mahalinga SubramaniyaM I tried putting only digits and then tabbed out of the input field, the digits were accepted. Should I put a submit button

Comment: @Anjali you can put submit button. Because your requirement i dont know

Comment: my requirements are extremely simple. User cannot type only digits in the input box. If the user only type digits then on submit button, they can see an error

Comment: @Anjali i have one doubt.
must give digits with alphabets. 
1. accept alphabets 
2.digits with alphabets
3.not accept digits

Comment: Accept alphabets, accept digits with alphabets, but do not accept only digits so if the user types only digits and no alphabets then don't accept it. If the user types only alphabets then accept it. If the user types both digits and alphabets then accept it.

Comment: @Anjali i updated post. Please check once

Comment: @Anjali my answer is wrong?